# How to Save multiple messages in Azure Function JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-functions

I have created one Azure function in Azure app which is triggered by IOT Hub, and it saves received messages in SQL database. but it is not able to handle when it receives multiple messages. my function is bellow.

```
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

for (var i = 0; i < iotHubMessage.length; i++) {

    var iotMsgObj = iotHubMessage[i];
    context.log('Message : ' + JSON.stringify(iotMsgObj));

    context.bindings.paraSession = JSON.stringify(iotMsgObj);   //to save data in SQL database

    context.done();         //  will save first message only
}

// context.done();     // will save last message only

};
```

when `iotHubMessage` hub has multiple JSON objects, it will save ether first or last message from `iotHubMessage` will store in database table.

please advice what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with SQL binding, but returning an array works for other types (e.g. queue):

```js
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

  context.bindings.paraSession = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < iotHubMessage.length; i++) {
    var iotMsgObj = iotHubMessage[i];
    context.bindings.paraSession.push(JSON.stringify(iotMsgObj));
  }

  context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikhail is right if you are storing data in Azure Table Storage. But when you are using SQL Database you need the following code snippet.

```
module.exports = function (context, iotHubMessage) {

var tempArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < iotHubMessage.length; i++) {
  var iotMsgObj = iotHubMessage[i];
  tempArr.push(iotMsgObj);
}

context.bindings.paraSession = tempArr;
context.done();
};
```